# Get a Postgres timestamp value from postgres date and postgres time

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a postgres date and posgres time column. Is there any postgres function to get postgres timestamp from these columns. This timestamp value is used to compare with the Java sql timestamp object.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)?

Comment: yes, but it does not solve my purpose

Comment: PostgreSQL supports string concatenation with CONCAT or with double pipeline (`||`).. double pipes does not work on date and time without casting but CONCAT does something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/340e0/123 should help you out

Comment: We need the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the database table.

Comment: create table sample (sys_date DATE NOT NULL, sys_time TIME WITH TIME ZONE );

Comment: It doesn't require any string concatenation, and it's right there in the beginning of the documentation, the `+` operator. A date value plus a time value will give you a timestamp value. Isn't that your purpose?

Comment: Thank You so much, it works !!!

Comment: @RealSkeptic I suggest making an Answer of your comment, so as to close this Question.

Comment: Just add them `sys_date + sys_time`. Btw: you shouldn't be using `timetz`: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sum the two columns using `+` operator. When you sum a **date** with a **time** type, you'll get a **timestamp** as the answer.

Look at the first table's third line.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html